# How should I memorise vector calculus identities?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

There are simply too many vector identities including $\nabla$. Every time I read a physics book I must learn some new ones. For example,
$$
\nabla\times (\nabla\times \mathbf f)=\nabla(\nabla\cdot \mathbf f)-\nabla^2\mathbf f,\\
\nabla(\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B})  \ =\ (\mathbf{A} {\cdot} \nabla)\mathbf{B} \,+\, (\mathbf{B}\, {\cdot} \nabla)\mathbf{A} \,+\, \mathbf{A} {\times} (\nabla {\times} \mathbf{B}) \,+\, \mathbf{B} {\times} (\nabla {\times} \mathbf{A}).
$$
Many of such identities contain four terms on RHS (unlike the two terms for chain rule of differentiation), and it is very difficult to remember the exact form of each of them.

Is there a fast way to understand many vector calculus identities quickly and intuitively? What should I learn first and what can be derived by myself?

Comment: I prefer to memorize only the *existence* of such identities, so that I know to look up the right-hand sides when needed.

Comment: Make a list of the identities that you know and come across and keep the list easily available. No need to memorize when you can just look at your list instead.